# Can not create UIImage and append it to array

Tags: swift

I have string array of file names, which looks like this

`["xBGEx.jpg", "OgJuM.jpg"]`

This is images, which saved to documents directory. I try to create array of UIImages by appending full path in for look and then appending to array.

In my appDelegate I have code in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` it looks like

```
    var paths:[AnyObject] = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)
    var documentsDirectory = paths[0] as? String
    self.documentsRoot = documentsDirectory! + "/"
```

Then, when Im in controller, which I need I do the following

```
var slider = ["xBGEx.jpg", "OgJuM.jpg"]
var UIImageArray = [UIImage]()

for element in imgArray {
        var path = "\(appDelegate.documentsRoot!)" + "\(element)"
        var obj:UIImage = UIImage(contentsOfFile: path)!
        UIImageArray.append(obj)
    }

imageArray = UIImageArray
```

but when I build I have nil error in the moment of appending
[image]

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains` returns an non-optional [String], any casting and optional binding is not needed at all. Apart from that I recommend the URL related API of `NSFilemanager` and the designated methods to append path components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the path doesn't lead to an image file.
You should check if the file you found a path for really is an image and not force the cast with `!`

```
for element in imgArray {
    var path = "\(appDelegate.documentsRoot!)" + "\(element)"
    if let obj = UIImage(contentsOfFile: path) {
        UIImageArray.append(obj)
    }   
}
```

On another note PLEASE don't name your variables with a capital letter
`uiImageArray` would be much better.